# CSS - problems with images/links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS for these lines, but they are not working in the way I want. There will be several similar lines like this(about 60).

First: all lines will use img src="staticimage.png". Is it possible to set this image as default in CSS(It will handle a link, set in the "a" tag before)?

Second: how can I remove the dimensioning code (width="50" align="right) from this image and put it in the CSS?

Here is my code:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="whiteborder"><img src="image1.png">Text 1<a href="linkone.html"><img src="staticimage.png" width="50" align="right"></a></div>
<div id="whiteborder"><img src="image2.png">Text 2<a href="linktwo.html"><img src="staticimage.png" width="50" align="right"></a></div>
<div id="whiteborder"><img src="image3.png">Text 3<a href="linkthree.html"><img src="staticimage.png" align="right"></a></div>
```

CSS code:

```
#whiteborder
{
    background: white;
    margin: 2px 10px 0px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:10px; 
}
```

PS: all texts with numbers will be different. I don't want any Javascript to set these lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to sort your image alignment out like this:

```
#whiteborder a img 
{
   width: 50px;
   float: right;
}
```

However, if you change your `a` tag to `display: block; float: right` and set a `background-image` on it, you can then dispense with the `img` and set the style for all those `a` tags in one place.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/TAhBT/)

Comment: I've just taken off this problem about the image as background. Is there any solution now?

Comment: @Claudio: if it was that easy to take off, then why put it on in the first place? ;)  See the demo in my answer - does that fit with what you need?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to build here but to address your individual queries:

1. You can't set "staticimage.png" as a default in any other way but as a background image using CSS
2. To remove the "dimensioning code" from the image HTML you can set **width:50px;** in your CSS and align it to the right with **float:right;**

Comment: Ok, I took the image background problem off, it can be set as background. Is there any solution now?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="whiteborder">
    <img src="image1.png">Text 1 <a href="linkone.html"></a>
    <img src="image2.png">Text 2 <a href="linktwo.html"></a>
    <img src="image3.png">Text 3 <a href="linkthree.html"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#whiteborder a{
    background: repeat-x url("staticimage.png");
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    ...
}
```

P.S. you shouldn't use the same id several times, but if you need you can use class instead